# Thirteen figures converted into NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Code i have try

```
NSString *time = @"1470067200000";    
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];       
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)([time doubleValue])/1000];       
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];        
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

**Result :** 2016-08-02 00:00

The **HH:mm** is always wrong, why?

Comment: you need to add your time zone

Comment: Your code returning `2016-08-01 21:30` in my system. I think this is okay. You can set timezone if you want for specific timezone. I think default is `UTC or GMT`

Answer (score 1):

Set Time Zone in the `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)([time doubleValue])/1000];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

NSDate always be in UTC and if you apply DateFormatter then default timezone in DateFormatter is localTimeZone. When I run the below code its giving me the below dates. Please check your device/simulator timezone

```
NSString *time = @"1470067200000";

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
   // [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)([time doubleValue])/1000];

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);


Printing description of date:
2016-08-01 16:00:00 +0000
Printing description of dateString: // after From NSDateFormatter 
2016-08-01 21:30
```

To get the stringFromDate in UTC from NSDateFormatter use below line

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```